# Center buttons and brand in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just starting out with Bootstrap and finding it very frustrating to do even simple things.

The "Brand" text in the Bootstrap navbar demo, along with the buttons, is left aligned. I want all of it to be centered. My code below centers the buttons, but when I center the "Brand" text it overlaps the buttons.

Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="margin: 0;">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="text-align: center;">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-media-query" style="float: none; display: inline-block;">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

Can anyone help me out? Also, I am struggling to see why Bootstrap (and other libs) are so popular. If you want to create a generic Bootstrap website it's very easy, but to do anything custom you have to hack the CSS together. It seems more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try moving `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>` from after the `</button>` tag to the line after `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-media-query" style="float: none; display: inline-block;">`.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar-media-query" style="float: none; display: inline-block;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

It worked for me.

However, note that this change will prevent the text 'Brand' from displaying in small screens by default, as it is now outside the `<navbar-header>` class. It is part of the `collapse` group now.

Additionally, if you wondered about this solution appearing strange... well. I find using an `a` tag under a `ul` weird too.

EDIT: `<li class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">Brand</a></li>` works too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked except for an issue in the mobile. Can you answer why these libraries are so popular? It has just been a pain for me. Centering these buttons should not be a difficult task.

Comment: I'm glad it did! As for why these libraries are so popular, I'm sure that one reason is that they allow beauty to be achieved with ease. I once tried replicating the code of a Twitter Bootstrap website without using the framework and it gave me nightmares! Another reason is that Bootstrap allows easy responsiveness, something which beginners could only dream about. [Here's a good read!](http://www.sitepoint.com/11-reasons-to-use-twitter-bootstrap/)